# Cronscript won't trigger ansible playbook automatically and no logging can be found

Tags: ansible, cron

There are certain lines in my crontab cannot be triggered automatically although I can trigger the ansible playbook manually.
I also cannot log the error as it didn't run the line. Some methods I had tried are including changing the ownership of the crontab and ansible playbook and allowing the crontab can be read. I had this line in my crontab right now:

`*/1  *    * * *   root   /bin/sh /home/ubuntu/ansibledir/cronscript/backup/cloud/cron_keycloak.sh >> /tmp/File.log 2>&1`

The file.log didnt show output of automatically triggered instead it only showing manually triggered output. What can I do to make it triggered on time automatically? ps. The other lines in crontab are working as expected.

Comment: check the OS log files and see what its saying about cron and its scheduled jobs

Comment: The log files in the os did prompt the line was triggered, but due to no mta installed the output was discarded.

Comment: This is not on-topic for SO, as described in the [help/on-topic], as it is more about system administration / configuration than about programming. The question have been answered before on ServerFault, though: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it. The usual suspects are: the crontab do not run as the user you think it does and the shell provided in cron is limited compared to a usual shell.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to include the log generation inside the script cron_keycloak.sh
   After the logic that you wish to execute  successfully immediate line end should redirect to the log file `ansible-playbook yourplaybook.yml >>/tmp/File.log`.
2. Update your crontab as follows:

   ```bash
   */1  * * * *   /home/ubuntu/ansibledir/cronscript/backup/cloud/cron_keycloak.sh
   ```

I think the `2>&1` is not suitable for your logic.